# how to remove objects that have all keys with null values in dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have this below payload and I want to remove object where all the keys have ALL empty values,

```
  [
    {
       "Order" : "123",
       "Product" : "456"
    },
    {
      "Order" : "",
      "Product" : ""
    }
  ]
```

This is what the output should be like,

```
   [
    {
       "Order" : "123",
       "Product" : "456"
    }
   ]
```

Comment: Note that the values you want to avoid are not null, they are empty strings.

Comment: that's true, sorry for that, I ll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

[image]

**Input**

```
[
    {
       "Order" : "123",
       "Product" : "456"
    },
    {
      "Order" : null,
      "Product" : null
    }
  ]
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Objects
var valuesOfInputObjects = payload map { ($ takeWhile((value, key) ->  value == null))}
---
payload -- valuesOfInputObjects
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    "Order": "123",
    "Product": "456"
  }
]
```

Comment: that seemed to have worked, I changed the condition and it worked, I will test it and let you know, thanks again.

Comment: this is not working in the input is like below
[
    {
       "Order" : "123",
       "Product" : "456"
    },
    {
      "Order" : null,
      "Product" : ""
    }
  ]

@apple123 please comment what condition you have put

Comment: The ask was to filter an object out if all the values were null in a given object. In your case the Product key in the second object is "" and not null. The script that i posted checks if all the values in an object are null , it would filter the entire object out. HTH

Comment: Salim you are right, it served the purpose instead of checking for null I changed it to value != "" and it worked.

Comment: IMO This is a very risky solution because it heavily relies on an assumption that a JSON  will be read in the exact same order twice. You should not keep your code rely on the way the mule reads JSON keys.

Comment: If you are referring to the -- operation being performed on the two datasets and there is a chance that they can be out of order?

Comment: That would be a bug (that would need to be fixed within the way its read (i.e. the implementation of map or takeWhile (making use of HashMap or Ordered Collections) and is possible . Otherwise you could do a recursion like Michael mentioned but if it he payload is huge you are then limited by the compute resources..

Comment: When using a json object, the entries can not be assumed ordered. In other words if a language reads your "second" entry first, you can not blame the language. Also the JSON standard clearly specifies that Entries in JSON Object are unordered.

Comment: The standard says that the object can have unordered keys  (while an array will have ordered elements). So the implementation at hand  can either enforce that by leaving it to the standard or can help provide some sanity by providing some sort of ordering guarantee (Again depends on what map or  takeWhile is implemented with - using Ordered Collection , hashMaps etc).

Answer (score 4):

None of the posted solutions handle things like nested structures or arrays, so I thought I'd throw this recursive solution in the ring. This allows us to traverse the entire structure of the object until we hit the first non-null field.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import everyEntry from dw::core::Objects
import every from dw::core::Arrays

var allFieldsNull = (obj: Any) ->
    obj match {
        case is Object -> obj everyEntry (allFieldsNull($))
        case is Array -> (sizeOf(obj) == 0) or (obj every allFieldsNull($))
        //case is Array -> false
        else -> isEmpty(obj)
    }

---
payload filter !allFieldsNull($)
```

If you wanted to consider an empty array as enough to keep the object since that technically isn't null, you would just need to comment out the `case is Array` line and uncomment the one below it.

Input:

```json
[
    {
       "Order" : "123",
       "Product" : "456"
    },
    {
      "Order" : "",
      "Product" : "",
      "Address": {
          "Field1": ""
      },
      "Test": [
        {
            "Order" : "",
            "Product" : "",
            "Address": {
                "Field1": ""
            }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Order" : null,
      "Product" : null,
      "Address": {
          "Field1": null
      },
      "Test": [
        {
            "Order" : null,
            "Product" : null,
            "Address": {
                "Field1": "A value even in a deeply nested field means I show up"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

output:

```json
[
  {
    "Order": "123",
    "Product": "456"
  },
  {
    "Order": null,
    "Product": null,
    "Address": {
      "Field1": null
    },
    "Test": [
      {
        "Order": null,
        "Product": null,
        "Address": {
          "Field1": "A value even in a deeply nested field means I show up"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by a condition, using the everyEntry() function to see that not all values are empty.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Objects
---
payload filter ($ someEntry (value, key) -> !isEmpty(value))
```

Comment: What this does is even if a single value is null in the object, it will reject it, rather what I want is that if all the value are null then only I want to remove it.