# How to remove key value pair from json using Dataweave in mule4

Tags: json, key, dataweave, mule4

I want to remove a key from json payload if its empty for eg.

```
{
    "transactionDetails": {
        "maintenanceType": null,
        "transactionDate": "2021-10-07T05:38:38.44-05:00"
    },
    "account": {
        "agentOfRecord": {
            "type": "true",
            "rateType": ""

        },
        "subAccounts": {
            "subAccount": [{

                "agentOfRecord": []
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example two keys which are empty "rateType" and "agentOfRecord". How can I remove this two keys from the payload.

Expected result will be lyk this

```
{
    "transactionDetails": {
        "maintenanceType": null,
        "transactionDate": "2021-10-07T05:38:38.44-05:00"
    },
    "account": {
        "agentOfRecord": {
            "type": "true"

        },
        "subAccounts": {
            "subAccount": [{

                
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried below code but not working its not filtering the actual key

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filterObject ((value, key) -> (key as String != "Test"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove objects that have all keys with null values in dataweave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66379290/how-to-remove-objects-that-have-all-keys-with-null-values-in-dataweave)

Comment: Not actually only need to remove two fields mentioned, there will be lot of fields with nullvalues

Answer (score 0):

The variable filterList is not used directly, so that the function is more reusable. The variable could be replaced by a list obtained from a configuration or a database.
This script should remove all keys mentioned in filterList that are 'empty'. I used a custom empty function, because the built-in isEmpty() function also includes empty objects, and I wasn't sure if you wanted that. Otherwise you can use the built-in version.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var filterList=["rateType", "agentOfRecord"]

fun isEmptyCustom(x)=
    x match  {
        case is Array -> sizeOf(x) == 0
        case is String -> sizeOf(x) == 0
        else -> false
    }


fun filterKey(k, v, f)= !isEmptyCustom(log("v",v)) or 
    !(f contains (log("k", k) as String))


fun filteKeyRecursive(x, f) = 
    x match {
        case is Object -> 
            x 
            filterObject ((value, key, index) ->  filterKey(key, value, f)) 
            mapObject  ($$): filteKeyRecursive($, f) 
        case is Array -> x map filteKeyRecursive($, f) 
        else -> x
  }
---
filteKeyRecursive(payload, filterList)
```

Update: fixed the condition.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the var filterList is not used inside the matching logic instead only used for recursive. Does this code removes all empty fields other than "rateType", "agentOfRecord" ?

Comment: I have added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: I had a logic error in my first answer. Fixed now.