# Mule 4.3 DataWeave Function Remove Empty

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

How to remove and clean out empty object or array from a complex payload. I tried using recursive function but seems it didn't work. In short, any value in the payload if it has an empty array or object, it should be remove from the output.

Comment: This question has been asked many times in the past. I suggest to search for similar answers in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove objects that have all keys with null values in dataweave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66379290/how-to-remove-objects-that-have-all-keys-with-null-values-in-dataweave)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function. It will look for an empty object or array and will be remove it.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun removeEmpty(a: Array) = a map removeEmpty($) filter (not isEmpty($))
fun removeEmpty(o: Object) = o mapObject 
     if (isEmpty($)) {} 
     else {($$): removeEmpty($)}
fun removeEmpty(s: String) = s
---
removeEmpty(payload)
```

It's a recursive function and it will check if it's an empty array or object.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'm new to DataWeave.